# Resize Google map on mouseover

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-maps-api-3

I want a Google map to resize when the user hovers over a small version of a map. Problem is that the mouseout event is also triggered when I hover the map navigation-elements:

JS:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mouseover', function() {
        $('#map_canvas').addClass('over',200);
});
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mouseout', function() {
        $('#map_canvas').removeClass('over',200);
});
```

The HTML element is just a simple `<div>`

```
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

The over class just adds some styles for the bigger view. It's animated using the jQuery UI animated Class changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried binding mouseenter and mouseleave to the containing div of the map and do it like that instead of mouseout/mouseover as an event listener on the map object?

```
$('#map').mouseenter(function() { 
/* add class */
 }).mouseleave(function() {
 /*remove class */ 
});
```

Comment: Yes, but after the Google map loads into the canvas/div the event doesn't get triggered

Comment: Ah true, because it gets added after the DOM content has loaded right? Have you tried `$('#map').live('mouseenter', function() { /* add.. */ }).live('mouseleave', function() { ... });`? live allows you to bind events to elements that are created and/or modified after the document is ready. I'd imagine it should work, but I haven't tested it first hand. The reason mouseout probably wasn't working was because `mouseout fires when the pointer moves out of the child element as well (ie onto nav controls), while mouseleave fires only when the pointer moves out of the bound element.` (jquery.com)

Comment: That also creates a bouncing effect... somehow the Google JS interferes with the jQuery. I've fixed it now by using a delay timer on the effect.